# Why the list items are not occupying the full with?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this modal to show some names:

```
 <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Names</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                             <ul class="modal-list">
                               @foreach($names as $name)
                                 <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                     <a  class=""  id="{{$name}}">{{$name}}</a>
                                 </li>
                               @endforeach
                             </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to have in each line 3 list items occupying the full with of the modal. As it is in on the bottom of the image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG2Qy.png)

But is not working properly, if there are for example only 3 names the results appears as it is in the top of he image above, occypying a very small width. Do you know why?

But it works fine, that is, as it is in the bottom of the image if there are more names like:

```
<ul class="modal-list">
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">John</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Peter</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Paul</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Ronald</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Boris</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Wayne</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Ron</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Jen</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Arnold</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Abe</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Bryant</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Carl</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Clement</a>
    </li>
    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Buck</a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
        <a class="">Cole</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Fiddle: But dont know why is not appearing as it is in the image: https://jsfiddle.net/9L161awx/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `row` class to the `ul` element:

```
<ul class="modal-list row">
```

The `row` class must be always the parent of the columns.